# Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.GlassLuceneIndex. No matching constructor was found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lucene, sitecore, glass-mapper

I just upgraded my Sitecore 7.2 instance to use the latest Glass Mapper SC Nuget packages (3.5.2.0).  I noticed when I try to rebuild my indexes Sitecore throws an error now:

Could not create instance of type: Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.GlassLuceneIndex. No matching constructor was found.

Anyone else seeing this problem?

Comment: Did you also add Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor and Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc packages?

Comment: Yes, both Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor (3.3.0.25)  and Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc (3.5.2.0) were updated/added to the project including nuget package Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider (3.5.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used NuGet package manager to remove Glass Mapper from the Visual Studio project and added Glass Mapper back in.  My error went away.

Answer (score 0):

This could be web activator issue

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(XYZ.Web.App_Start.GlassMapperSC), "Start")]
```

Add this line on the top of your class file